# How to prove this in Coq

Tags: coq, coqide

```
Lemma x: forall P Q: Set -> Prop,
              forall f: Set -> Set, 
            forall x, (P x -> Q (f x)) -> 
               (exists x, P x) -> (exists x, Q x).
```

I try to do it many different ways and I dont know whats wrong. This is my latest attempt:

```
Lemma x: forall P Q: Set -> Prop,
              forall f: Set -> Set, 
            forall x, (P x -> Q (f x)) -> 
               (exists x, P x) -> (exists x, Q x).
Proof.
  intros P Q f x H1 [x0 H2].
  exists (f x0).
  apply H1.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

but it produces this error: In environment
P, Q : Set -> Prop
f : Set -> Set
x : Set
H1 : P x -> Q (f x)
x0 : Set
H2 : P x0
Unable to unify "Q (f x)" with "Q (f x0)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Lemma is actually false. Here is a proof that it is false:

```
Axiom x: forall P Q: Set -> Prop,
              forall f: Set -> Set, 
            forall x, (P x -> Q (f x)) -> 
               (exists x, P x) -> (exists x, Q x).


Lemma false : False.
Proof.
  destruct (x 
  (* P *) inhabited
  (* Q *) (fun _ => False)
  (* f *) (fun _ => False)
  (* x *) False ) as [y Hy].
  (* P x -> Q (f x) *) 
  - intros [[]]. (* trivially true, as False is not inhabited *)
  (* ∃ x, P x *) 
  - exists True. now apply inhabits.
  (* We get to assume that Q is satisfiable, but Q is always False *)
  - apply Hy.
Qed.
```

However, it is likely that the lemma you are trying to prove is not the one you want to prove. Is it possible you wanted to prove this lemma here instead?

```
Lemma x_fixed: forall P Q: Set -> Prop,
               forall f: Set -> Set, 
               (forall x, P x -> Q (f x)) -> 
               (exists x, P x) -> (exists x, Q x).
Proof.
  intros P Q f H1 [x0 H2].
  exists (f x0).
  apply H1.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

The difference is that the assumption is `forall x, P x -> Q (f x)`, instead of just being `P x -> Q (f x)` for one specific `x` that is not otherwise mentioned in your goal (since it is shadowed by both `exists x, P/Q x`).